# how do I install 12.04 when I am using 13.8?

Tags: 12.04

how do I install 12.04 when I am using 13.8? Is there a way to go back to 12.04 or do I have to install it over the old OS?

Comment: Do you mean 13.04 or 13.10? no you can not just go back, you have to reinstall but you can back up your important data first.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a downgrade (from whatever version 13.8 is; there is 13.04, which is EOL, and 13.10). You will have to do a full re-install.

Comment: You can download the disk image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and follow [these installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support).